# Is there a way to prepend a certain group of functions with another function call in C?

Tags: c, macros, access-control

I have a set of functions that I wish to be called only if the calling process have a certain permission. I have a working access control module which will do the check, I just want to define this group of function in one place and not have to do it manually every time it's called in-code.

So, say if one such protected function is `fread()`, I want a call to be made: `accessCheck(processId,fread)` without having to type this out specifically in the place I want the call to be made. Can I define `fread()` in some way, in some place so that it is always "`protected`" like this?

This is in `C` btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a macro for each protected function as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#undef fread
#define fread(ptr, size, n, fp) \
    (accessCheck(getpid(), (void (*)(void))fread ? (ssize_t)-1 : \
     fread((ptr), (size), (n), (fp)))
```

Here, `getpid()` is the function that returns the current process ID and `accessCheck` has the prototype:

```
int accessCheck(pid_t pid, void (*fn)(void));
```

Here, `pid_t` is the type of the process ID. `fn` is of a generic function pointer of type `(void (*)(void))`. `fn` which will not be called by `accessCheck`, only the pointer value will be checked. `accessCheck` should return 0 on success or some non-zero value on failure. On failure `accessCheck` should also set `errno` to a suitable value.

The `#include <stdio.h>` and `#undef fread` lines are because `#include <stdio.h>` is allowed to define a macro `fread` that behaves the same as the function `fread` (although it seems unlikely that it would do so), and we want to replace that macro.  The references to `fread` within the macro's replacement text are fine because C macros are not recursive.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Would it be possible to declare this macro, or something similar, in a separate file and have it work the same way. Imagine having several protected functions, it would be great to be able to define them all in one place.

Comment: Yes, you can declare the macro in a .h file included by the .c files. The main problem is that it is easy to forget to include the .h file and bypass the macro when calling `fread` or whatever. You cannot really prevent code from bypassing the macro, so you need to audit your code if you need to enforce use of the macro.